# EdgeLabels in a Web Structure Visualization

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, visualization, mathematica-8

I've been playing around with Mathematica's visualization and webcrawling capabilities. Building on some demonstration code, I'm able to visualize the a network. Here's an example on a university webpage:

```
webcrawler[rooturl_, depth_] :=
  Flatten[Rest[NestList[
       Union[Flatten[Thread[# -> Import[#,"Hyperlinks"]] & /@ Last /@ #]] &, 
       {"" -> rooturl}, depth]]];

Graph[webcrawler[
  "http://www.yorku.ca/", 2], {ImageSize -> Full}]
```

However, I've been trying fruitlessly to figure out a way to apply EdgeLabels[] to this `Graph[]` command. I would like to have each link written on each line, just to give a sense of what exactly the link clusters represent.

I've tried applying a generated list of the Hyperlink connections to it, which didn't work, and neither did any of the readily obvious commands from documentation/elsewhere on stack/the cookbook.

I envision a very cluttered output.

Comment: Your code was missing a leading `{`, and I'm not sure if I got it right. So, please check it.

Comment: I ran your code (with @rcollyer mods) and your graph is so cluttered that I doubt any labeling will be useful.

Comment: @rcollyer It is working on my system now..  my apologies, I must have messed it up when pasting it into the system. Thank you for catching the error.

Comment: @belisarius It is quite cluttered, but helpful for my specific application. But certainly a very important and helpful proviso to raise in case anybody else wants to go down this crazy road...

Comment: @ian I guess a meaningful mapping for a web site requires other approaches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know in case of a large graph how will the edge label look. But here how it can be done in Mathematica 8.

```
webcrawler[rooturl_, depth_] := 
Flatten[Rest[
NestList[
 Union[Flatten[
    Thread[# -> Import[#, "Hyperlinks"]] & /@ 
     Last /@ #]] &, {"" -> rooturl}, depth]]];
dats = webcrawler["http://www.uni-kl.de/", 2];
Graph[dats ,EdgeLabels ->Table[dats[[i]] -> dats[[i]][[2]],
{i,Length[dats]}], {ImageSize -> Full}]
```

[image]
I hope this helps.

BR

Comment: Great - thanks very much. Believe it or not, this helps a lot.

Comment: The variable `el` in the last line seems to be undefined

Answer (score 6):

**Place `EdgeLabels` inside `Tooltip`s**

The following will display the names of both the edges and the vertices as tooltips. (You can remove the `VertexLabels`, of course.  I included them because the `EdgeLabels` were often very long.)

```
data = webcrawler["http://www.yorku.ca/", 2];
Graph[data,
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip],
   EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line",
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip], 
   EdgeStyle -> {Orange},
   VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.007},
   ImageSize -> 800]
```

It should be helpful for browsing the network. But of course, it will not print out the labels.

Comment: `EdgeLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip]` is an alternative to displaying all the edge labels on screen at once.

Comment: This is a very helpful alternative - great!

Comment: I thought of using Tooltips too. My implementation used Graph[Tooltip[#, #[[2]]] & /@ data]. Didn't know about this `Placed` alternative.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries As of version 8, there are lots of little goodies waiting to be used with Graphs. I wanted to make a window into the network using NeighborhoodGraph, but found that a little too complicated.

Comment: @Belisarius Nice. And strikingly familiar. But for some reason the popup window for  edges is always empty.  (BTW, my problem with NeighborhoodGraph was peculiar to the `webcrawler` data: for some reason mma would not return a graph when I used the data about URL's.  Not sure why.